# Circular View Path Exception in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to return "index.html" page for every request mapping with below controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class ReactWebController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login/**", "/logout/**", "/forgotpassword/**", "/home/**", "/dashboard/**"
            , "/user/**", "/profile/**", "/catalog/**", "/permission/**", "/diconnect/**", "/nsm/**", "/session/**"
            , "/settings/**", "/log/**", "/config/**", "/delete/**", "/initialize/**", "/initial/**", "/changepassword/**",
            "/portalconnect/**", "/portal/**", "/portal/user/**", "/portal/profile/**", "/portal/permission/**",
            "/portal/catalog/**", "/portal/metadata-browse/**","/portal/search/**","/portal-object-overview/**"})
    public String react() throws Exception {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I refresh URL it is working when the path is like this: http://localhost:18170/MartServer/user, but not when it has multiple folder kind of paths e.g. http://localhost:18170/MartServer/portal/user. I get below exception details.

**EDIT:** But it is not the case in port 3000 (frontend) where I didn't do any build of complete project, backend and frontend are separate.

```
ERROR [/MartServer].[dispatcherServlet].log: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/MartServer] threw exception [Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/MartServer/portal/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/MartServer/portal/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

I tried to add `addViewControllers()` and `addResourceHanlders()` as well, but no luck. Can anyone help me how to fix this. Thanks!

Frontend is React JS, index.html is generated after "npm run build" and is used for controller

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the below mentioned properties and see if they help your case:

1. Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` on your *ReactWebController* class.
2. Add a custom **context-path** to the `application.properties` file of your spring-boot application:

> server.servlet.context-path=MartServer/portal

3. You could also make use of a **View Resolver**. It can be configured in the `application.properties` file, as shown below:

> ```
> spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
> spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
> ```

Check out the official [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server) for further details on configurable properties.

Comment: First 2 points are absolutely wrong. 3rd also wrong as the view gets rendered for /user so it is clear that view resolver working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it is correct to throw you an exception because:
you call the http://localhost/MartServer/portal/user which results the path http://localhost/MartServer/portal/index.html. You defined the paths `"/portal/**"` and `"/portal/user/**"` in your controller => the path match again.

I think that is better to review all your paths.

For example if you let `"/portal/**"` it will also match the path for http://localhost/MartServer/portal/user. But this depends of what you want to achieve.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? If I remove /portal/**, I get nothing that has portal in its URL.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by: "you get nothing that has portal in its URL"? As far as I see you map "/portal/**" - which is a general path and this path also matches "/portal/user/**".... the think is either you use general path like "/portal/**" or you define all sub specific paths like "/portal/user/**"

Comment: I mean even if I give sub specific paths or general path, both ways it is not working when I do refresh